# How to add constraint programmatically to UITextField.leftView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating a function to add image to leftView of UITextField and below is the code that I tried.

```
func setLeftImageWithColor(image:UIImage, color:UIColor, textField:UITextField) {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.backgroundColor = color
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
    textField.leftView = imageView
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always

    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: txtUsername, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: txtUsername, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: txtUsername, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let aspectRatioConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: (txtUsername.frame.size.height / txtUsername.frame.size.width), constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint, aspectRatioConstraint])

}
```

It gives an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
>    and
>    because they have no
>   common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items
>   in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

and if I don't add any constraint then view is like this

[image]

and this is the image that I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: have you tried textfield accessory view?

Comment: Try changing `NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, ...` to `NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField.leftView, ...`

Answer (score 6):

Try setting frame directly in `layoutSubviews` of the view containing the textView:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    textField.leftView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textField.bounds.height, height: textField.bounds.height)
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per request to work only with constraints, let us have a look a bit how `leftView` works with `UITextField`.

From experiments it seems that the `UITextField` adds its `leftView` to its view hierarchy only when it needs to. So simply doing:

```
textField.leftView = imageView
```

Will NOT make the `imageView` a part of a view hierarchy. That's why you get the crash if you try to create constraints right after doing that.

There is a way how to force it to put it to view hierarchy, and that's by forcing autolayout on the `textField`:

```
// add it as a leftView
textField.leftView = imageView

// force autolayout on textField
self.textField.setNeedsLayout()
self.textField.layoutIfNeeded()

// add constraints now
```

Comment: Yes I know that but I am asking for solution with constraint only. So just function will do all the work and there is no need for override layoutSubviews and handling multiple UITextField frame

Comment: @VarunNaharia at you're request, the update with a workaround for constraints :)

Comment: app is not crashing but it looks like constraints are not working do you have any idea what's wrong with constraints

Comment: @VarunNaharia well.. not sure.. but based on the existence of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619586-leftviewrect  method there, I would just guess that they have not yet prepared `leftView` of the text field to be positioned/sized by the autolayout.. I guess you'll be stuck with `layoutSubviews` override (although in your case I would probably consider subclassing `UITextField` and adding the logic there)

Answer (score 0):

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

```
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    diameterText.frame = CGRect(x: diameterLabel.frame.origin.x, y: diameterLabel.frame.origin.y + 10, width: view.frame.width - diameterLabel.frame.origin.x * 2, height: 35)

    heightText.frame = CGRect(x: heightlabel.frame.origin.x, y: heightlabel.frame.origin.y + 10, width: view.frame.width - heightlabel.frame.origin.x * 2, height: 35)
}
```

Thanks it is working for me..